# How can I change labels created with build_menu_from_desktop() in pythons appindicator module?

Tags: unity, indicator, python, application-development

Suppose I created an indicator with appindicator for python. Suppose I used the line `build_menu_from_desktop("/my/path/myfile.desktop", "Unity")` for that. How would I go about changing the created menu-items? Their labels for example?

Comment: Part of the answer in: http://askubuntu.com/q/46746/17789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is partially answered in

[Is there a detailed API documentation on the python binding for appindicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46746/is-there-a-detailed-api-documentation-on-the-python-binding-for-appindicator)

The answer is: loading the gtk desktop file produces a GtkMenus object *somewhere* which you should be able to get the gtk menu object out of by looking at it's children.

I can't find good documentation for what the build_menu_from_desktop returns, if you can't investigate the code manually to find the answer then hunt down Ted Gould who will be able to answer it. Finding the Gtk objects is the answer though.

Otherwise follow the advice for Ted in the question above, you shouldn't be using the convenience function, instead you should be building the menus manually or loading a glade file if you want the menu entries to be separated into another file. (don't forget to tie methods to their click events in that case)