# How do I get the names in my icon theme for use with pythons appindicator module?

Tags: indicator, python, themes, icons, application-development

How do I get the strings I can insert instead of 'gtk-execute'?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gobject
import gtk
import appindicator

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ind = appindicator.Indicator("example-simple-client", "gtk-execute",
        appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
    ind.set_status (appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)

    menu = gtk.Menu()

    for i in range(3):
        buf = "Test-undermenu - %d" % i
        menu_items = gtk.MenuItem(buf)
        menu.append(menu_items)
        menu_items.connect("activate", gtk.main_quit)
        menu_items.show()

    ind.set_menu(menu)
    gtk.main()
```

My [answer below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46761/how-do-i-get-the-names-in-my-icon-theme-for-use-with-pythons-appindicator-module/46763#46763) pretty much does it. **Still it would be nice to have some python code that puts out all available icons.**

Comment: It would help if you gave a quick python example that we can run to test. (current code does nothing for me)

Comment: Found one [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python%20version) for those wondering.

Comment: Example-Code added. It's basically the code in your link with a small twist

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme()
print(icon_theme.list_icons())
```

The output of which is a tuple of all the icon names:

```
('input-gaming', 'gnome-aorta', 'stock_bottom', 'config-language', ...)
```

<sub>See also: [Gtk.IconTheme.list_icons](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/IconTheme.html#Gtk.IconTheme.list_icons) in the Gtk-3.0 docs</sub>

If you'd like to get your icon as a **GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf**, you can use the [`load_icon`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/IconTheme.html#Gtk.IconTheme.load_icon) method:

```
>>> icon_theme.load_icon("gtk-execute", 48, 0)
<GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf object at 0x7fd1689a5d80 (GdkPixbuf at 0x2ad45e0)>
```

If you want a **filename** instead, you can use the [`lookup_icon`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/IconTheme.html#Gtk.IconTheme.lookup_icon) method:

```
>>> icon_theme.lookup_icon("gtk-execute", 48, 0).get_filename()
/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/actions/gtk-execute.png
```

Where `48` is the size of the desired icon (see also: [`get_icon_sizes`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/IconTheme.html#Gtk.IconTheme.get_icon_sizes)).

Answer (score 1):

**Shameless selfanswer**: http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gtk2/Stock.html

**Edit**:
No not really. <strike>Wrong</strike> incomplete answer. For instance "indicator-messages" is not included in that list.

**Update**:
In the folder `/usr/share/icons/MYTHEME` where `MYTHEME` denotes the name of the theme in use should be the icons. Will test that now.

**Update2**:
Yes all icons in the aforementioned folder work! And the themes have fallbacks for items not found. The ones in gtk-stock mentioned in the link earlier are from the fallbacks. Would be nice to have some python code that puts out all available icons. One fare good using standard-items of the gtk-stock and the default-theme only, as the others' presence depends on the theme the user employs on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It follows regular icon naming, which will, as far as I know, start at your theme and then keep falling back till it matches something with the name.

Taking for example the Faenza icon theme I currently use.

In `/usr/share/icons/Faenza/index.theme` it says (clipped)

```
[Icon Theme]
Name=Faenza
Inherits=gnome,hicolor
Comment=Icon theme project with tilish style, by Tiheum
Directories=actions/16,animations/16,apps/16,categories/16,devices/16,emblems/16,mimetypes/16,places/16,status/16,stock/16,actions/22,animations/22,apps/22,categories/22,devices/22,emblems/22,mimetypes/22,places/22,status/22,stock/22,actions/24,animations/24,apps/24,categories/24,devices/24,emblems/24,mimetypes/24,places/24,status/24,stock/24,actions/32,animations/32,apps/32,categories/32,devices/32,emblems/32,mimetypes/32,places/32,status/32,stock/32,actions/48,animations/48,apps/48,categories/48,devices/48,emblems/48,mimetypes/48,places/48,status/48,stock/48,actions/scalable,apps/scalable,categories/scalable,devices/scalable,emblems/scalable,mimetypes/scalable,places/scalable,status/scalable,stock/scalable
```

Notice the `Inherits=...` line? Those are Faenza's "fallbacks" in case it doesn't have the icon itself.

This is relevant to your question, because you can enter a name for an icon and then the icon will first be searched for in `/usr/share/icons/YOURICONTHEME/`. In the odd case that it doesn't find it, it will check the fallbacks (in this case `/usr/share/icons/gnome/` and `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/`). You'll find that most (Ubuntu) icon themes inherit from `gnome` and/or `hicolor` so if you use the name of an icon in these folders, you can most likely rest assured that every theme will show an icon.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a GUI application showing all icons, as shown in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/641155/169577):

[`gtk3-icon-browser`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/IconBrowser)