# How to use custom icon in an appindicator?

Tags: indicator, python, gtk, application-development

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46761/how-do-i-get-the-names-in-my-icon-theme-for-use-with-pythons-appindicator-module) has already which icon names you can pass to the [`set_icon_full`](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-11.10/c/appindicator/libappindicator-app-indicator.html#app-indicator-set-icon-full) (`set_icon` is deprecated if someone is wondering), but I couldn't find ressources of how to set a custom icon from a file coming with the application?

- Is it generally recommended (because icons shipped with the application won't change with icon theme)?
- How to accomplish it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a quick look at the documentation, have you set [icon-theme-path](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-11.10/c/appindicator/libappindicator-app-indicator.html#AppIndicator--icon-theme-path) to point to the icon's installed location?

Comment: After calling `set_icon_theme_path` you can reference `your-icon.png` under the "icon name" `your-icon`. Thanks a lot.